# Разработать программу поиска номеров всех элементов масива, больших чем предыдущие

Tags: c++, массивы

```
    #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
       
    int number = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int count = 0;
    
     cout << "Rozmer masiva А: ";
     cin >> size;
     int* arr = new int[size];
     cout << "Vvedite chisla masiva A: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                cout << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << ": ";
                cin >> arr[i];
                arr[i] = number;
            }
    cout << endl;       
    
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int b;
           if(b > number) {
              cout << b << " ";
           }
           number = b;
        }
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Не могу разобраться с цыклом for для вывода элементов больших чем предыдущие. Затея была в том чтобы присвоим переменной b значение number, чтобы иметь возможность сравнивать и далее. Но ничего не вышло

Comment: Больших, чем один предыдущий, или все предыдущие?

Comment: чем один предыдущий

Answer (score 1):

Для случая, когда нужно сравнивать только с одним предыдущим - логика очень простая. Обратите внимание на старт цикла со второго элемента.

```
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i-1])
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Кстати, в заголовке сказано "поиска **номеров** всех..." - если нужно именно так, выводите `i`, а не `arr[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Числа могут быть и отрицательными, поэтому нужно сначала иметь для сравнения самое маленькое число, что вместится в int.

```
   int number = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {       
        if (number < arr[i]) {
            cout << i << ' ';
            number = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

Строка `int count = 0;` лишняя, можете удалить. А присвоение  и `arr[i] = number; в первом цикле` и `int number = 0;` удалите обязательно.

Comment: Может всё таки так: int number = arr[0], а for c 1. И number = arr[i]; за if. В задаче - больше предыдущего, а у arr[0] - нет предыдущего